# unix command to filter the json

Tags: json, shell, unix, curl

```
[
   {
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-aa",
      "hash":"010d126f8ccf199f3cd5f468a90d5ae1",
      "bytes":4294967296,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-10T01:32:00.069000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   },
   {
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ab",
      "hash":"49a6f22068228f51488559c096aa06ce",
      "bytes":397973601,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-10T01:32:22.395000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   },
   {
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ac",
      "hash":"2c5e845f46357e203214592332774f4c",
      "bytes":5179281858,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-11T08:20:11.566000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   }
]
```

I am getting above JSON as response while listing the objects in cloud  object storage using `curl -l -X GET`. How can I get the object "name" assigned to an array while looping through all the objects.
for example

```
array[1]="sandboxserver.tar.gz.part- aa"
array[2]="sandboxserver.tar.gz.part- ab"
array[3]="sandboxserver.tar.gz.part- ac"
```

Comment: Please paste your expected output properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to depend on external utility like jq, use can use python + bash combo do the trick.

```
response="$(cat data.json)"
declare -a array
array=($(python -c "import json,sys; data=[arr['name'] for arr in json.loads(sys.argv[1])]; print('\n'.join(data));" "$response"))

echo "${array[@]}"
```

Advice: Writing embedded python code may soon become unreadable so you may want to put the python code in a separate script and run the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jq`.

```
jq is a powerful tool that lets you read, filter, and write JSON in bash.
```

You might need to install it first.

Try this:

I've pasted your json into a file:

```
~$ cat n1.json
[  
   {  
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-aa",
      "hash":"010d126f8ccf199f3cd5f468a90d5ae1",
      "bytes":4294967296,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-10T01:32:00.069000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   },
   {  
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ab",
      "hash":"49a6f22068228f51488559c096aa06ce",
      "bytes":397973601,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-10T01:32:22.395000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   },
   {  
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ac",
      "hash":"2c5e845f46357e203214592332774f4c",
      "bytes":5179281858,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-11T08:20:11.566000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   }
]
```

And then used `jq` to find the names:

```
~$ jq -r '.[].name' n1.json
sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-aa
sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ab
sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ac
```